# Editor placeholder in source file when there is no placeholder

Tags: arrays, swift, placeholder

I tried to use the `filter` method on an array of visible table view cell but the compiler complains that I have placeholder text when there clearly isn't any: [image of compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqalA.png)
The method is called in an extension of a view controller. The same code compiles absolutely fine in other parts of the same file in another extension of the view controller.

I've been using these types of methods very frequently so I don't understand why Xcode is suddenly deciding to complain now.

Comment: Often these weird errors can be resolved by deleting the contents of your derived data folder and restarting Xcode. (FWIW, I’m seeing more of these annoyances than I did in Xcode 10. Even in brand new projects.)

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I'm embarrassed to have made such a rookie mistake

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to try deleting derived data and/or restart Xcode